# How can I achieve this design using MUI components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to achieve a design similar to the screenshot below using MUI. Is there a possible combination of Autocomplete, TextField, Checkbox, Popper, Chip etc to design this?

There is a Autocpmplete search bar on the top. The selected checked items should appear in the box as removable Chip. There is also a Select All and Clear All button and options nested as parent and child.

[image: Autocomplete Search Select Checkbox]

Comment: can you show what you did?

Comment: You need to customize autocomplete. You can use `renderTags`, `renderOption` like tags to customize. Check [MUI Autocomplete API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/) and this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/0nrho?file=/src/App.js:3838-3850)